# How to use AppDelegate in test cases?

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode5, appdelegate, xctest

In multiple classes, I'm using `[NSApp delegate]` to get my main AppDelegate from where I'm accessing some properties. This is working as expected, but when I *Unit Test* the code that uses this, this delegate is *nil*.

How can I handle this in my test? Is it possible to write a mock or something?

Comment: What properties are these?  It sounds like they need to be in different class, other than App Delegate; perhaps using the singleton model.

Comment: For instance I have a custom *UserSettings* property. You are right, maybe it makes sense to put this property elsewhere. I just see the AppDelegate as a global class accessible from anywhere, which makes it a good choice for storing global data.

Comment: In this case though, it's convenient to have a different class, that doesn't act as the app's delegate store these properties.  It should be easy to move and implement.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to add a static method to the UserSettings class, which can deliver a global instance of UserSettings object, that I can use in classes around my app. Should I just add a static instance variable to hold this instance and a static method to deliver this? Could this be a fair solution?

Comment: No, I think making it a first class, err, class, will benefit in the long run.  It's really no work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate singleton class, that can be used to store global properties, and leave App Delegate to do its delegation role and nothing more:

AppProperties.h:

```
@interface AppProperties : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *prop1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *prop2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *prop3;

+ (AppProperties *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

AppProperties.m:

```
@implementation AppProperties

@synthesize prop1, prop2, prop3;

+ (AppProperties *)sharedInstance {
    static AppProperties *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[AppProperties alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

@end
```